# Accessing roles' defaults variables

Tags: ansible

**Hello, everyone !!**

I have probably a silly problem... Didn't find someone else who have the same issue as me. I am trying to create a role to handle user/group/ssh_key creation which should be quite simple. But here is my issue...

First of all let me present you the architecture:

```
root
├── all.yml
├── ansible.cfg
├── commun.yml
├── hosts
└── roles
    └── commun
        ├── defaults
        │   └── main
        │       ├── groups.yml
        │       ├── home_config.yml
        │       ├── packages.yml
        │       └── users.yml
        ├── files
        ├── handlers
        ├── tasks
        │   ├── config.yml
        │   ├── groups.yml
        │   ├── main.yml
        │   ├── packages.yml
        │   └── users.yml
        └── templates
```

I got the following statement in `commun/defaults/main/users.yml`:

```
---
users:
  segar_h:
    fullname: "John Doe"
    groups:
      - "admins"
    ssh_keys:
      - "ssh-rsa xxxxx"
```

and in `commun/tasks/users.yml`

```
---
- name: "Ensure the user '{{ item }}' exists"
  user:
    include: users.yml
    name: "{{ item }}"
    groups: "{{ item.groups }}"
    state: present
    createhome: yes
    append: yes
    shell: /bin/zsh
    system: yes
  with_items:
    - users


- name: "Ensure the user '{{ item }}' accepts the SSH key"
  authorized_key:
    user: "{{ item }}"
    key: "{{ item.ssh_keys }}"
    state: present
    path: "/etc/ssh/keys/%u/authorized_keys"
  with_items:
    - users
```

Not sure if I am doing this right but, I can't seem to understand on how to access the variables I declared for this role.
All I am trying to do is to loop on every declared users and create a home for him. Same goes for the ssh keys specific of that user.

I got the following error message:

```
{"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'groups'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/xxx/commun/tasks/users.yml': line 2, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n---\n- name: \"Ensure the user '{{ item }}' exists\"\n  ^ here\nWe could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with\nmissing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they\nstart a value. For instance:\n\n    with_items:\n      - {{ foo }}\n\nShould be written as:\n\n    with_items:\n      - \"{{ foo }}\"\n"}
```

Am I doing something wrong ? Is there way of doing that without declaring the variables inside the task ? Like the following statement:
Can you provide an example/ressource so I can look into ?

```
---
- name: "example task"
  vars: 
    - users1:
        name
  user:
  [...]
```

Thank you in advance for you help !

PS: I am coming from Saltstack... Sorry if it's newbie a question.

**Issue #2 ?**

I am declaring the variables as lists as you told me.

```
---
groups:
  - name: admins
    sudo: True
```

The following task doesn't work with the same issue :

**Task**

```
- name: "print each group details"
  debug:
    msg: "name: {{ item.name }}, sudo: {{ item.sudo }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ groups }}"
```

**Error msg**

```
FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'name'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/xxx/commun/tasks/groups.yml': line 2, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n-
--\n- name: \"print each group details\"\n  ^ here\n"}
```

**Solution Issue #2**
Seems like the `group` variable is being override but the inventory variables.

Comment: documentation says: `To create defaults, simply add a defaults/main.yml file in your role directory. These variables will have the lowest priority of any variables available, and can be easily overridden by any other variable, including inventory variables.` i am not sure if your `defaults` dir contents is correct, but havent tried it myself.

Comment: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/14248 
this is a feature that has been added.

Comment: You are right, i tested and seem its loading the files from `main` directory. is the way you declare the users list open for modifications? i can suggest some changes  that i believe you will find them to make more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

judging by the task in `commun/tasks/users.yml`, the `users` is supposed to be a list (with 1 item in your current example, but i guess it may have more in the future). You should change the task `with_items` declaration to this format:

```
  with_items:
  - "{{ users }}"
```

and the proper way to declare a `list` variable in yml syntax requires to start each element with an `-`. But additionally, i would add a `name` attribute in each "user" element of your list, making the syntax in this format. complete file, with a 2nd user added as an example:

```
---
users:
-  name: segar_h
   fullname: "John Doe"
   groups:
   - "admins"
   ssh_keys:
   - "ssh-rsa xxxxx"
-  name: nick_dalton
   fullname: "Nick Dalton"
   groups:
   - "admins"
   ssh_keys:
   - "ssh-rsa xxxxx12"
```

and here is a sample task to parse the attributes of each user:

```
---
- name: print each users details
  debug:
    msg: "name: {{ item.name }}, 1st group: {{ item.groups[0] }}, ssh_keys: {{ item.ssh_keys }}"
  with_items:
  - "{{ users }}"
```

the above will print:

```
TASK [test : print each users details] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'segar_h', 'fullname': 'John Doe', 'groups': ['admins'], 'ssh_keys': ['ssh-rsa xxxxx']}) => {
    "msg": "name: segar_h, 1st group: admins, ssh_keys: ['ssh-rsa xxxxx'], name: {'name': 'segar_h', 'fullname': 'John Doe', 'groups': ['admins'], 'ssh_keys': ['ssh-rsa xxxxx']}"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'nick_dalton', 'fullname': 'Nick Dalton', 'groups': ['admins'], 'ssh_keys': ['ssh-rsa xxxxx12']}) => {
    "msg": "name: nick_dalton, 1st group: admins, ssh_keys: ['ssh-rsa xxxxx12'], name: {'name': 'nick_dalton', 'fullname': 'Nick Dalton', 'groups': ['admins'], 'ssh_keys': ['ssh-rsa xxxxx12']}"
}
```

hope these help!

Comment: Sorry coming back to this issue... I think I still got the issue... weirdly enough I am doing what you told me => use lists when declaring variables.
I edited the question for some the new issue...

Comment: can you dump the `groups` variable to see if its the one you defined? there is a `groups` variable automatically generated from the inventory and probably overrides yours. You could name yours `users_groups` or something.

Comment: Seems like your right ! But I would like to know more about this. How would you dump the variables that are loaded ? Where can I find the variables that are automatically generated ?

Comment: the ultimate resource is the [official documentation site](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html?highlight=variables). to dump, you can use `debug` module with `var` or `msg` parameter passed. to view all vars loaded, i usually use debug module with: `var: hostvars`